# replacement of the python facebook API?

Tags: python, django, facebook, api

as stated in bug [#17429](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17429), official support for the python api is ending, does anyone know of a up-to-date facebook api for python? or should I look for another language or web framework?

Comment: According to that ticket support for **SDK** ends. The whole facebook API is language/technology agnostic and just a regular OAuth-based RESTful one.

Comment: @zerkms That should be an answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to that ticket support for **SDK** ends. The whole facebook API is language/technology agnostic and just a regular OAuth-based RESTful one

Answer (score 3):

> [...] does anyone know of a up-to-date facebook api for python?

[Facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Facepy great- uses [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-get-request), doubly great

Answer (score 0):

While I develop Facebook apps in PHP (still supported), I switched to mainly using the javascript SDK. I think it's a better user experience and Facebook automatically upgrades it when they change the rules. Which seems quite often. Typically, there isn't any change required in your javascript code.

Comment: When you use JS SDK - you can only work with the data on client side. Nothing can be persisted and processed on the server.

Comment: True, it does introduce some limitations. But you can implement permission requests and all the "viral" features in the JS SDK and log everything to the server (ie. wall posts, requests) for tracking. On the backend you can then just implement the bare minimum needed through the graph API.

Answer (score -1):

Django Facebook is mature:
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

There's nothing language/framework agnostic about the facebook API.

The open graph api has it's own syntax.
Oauth takes care of authentication, but you still need to convert the output data to something your app can work with.